# Why doesn't audio context work correctly on firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, audiocontext

A while ago I made [this](http://masterzagh.github.io/musiccircle/), which uses the browser's `AudioContext` to create an `Analyser` and give me audio data so that I can animate the music being played.

When I finished this at the time it worked perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox. When I tried it recently it still worked in Chrome but didn't work correctly in Firefox.

Whenever I try to skip through the song or change the source in Firefox the audio stops playing and I stop receiving Analyser data.

#### Initialization

```
//Creating audio
this.audio = document.createElement("audio");
this.audio.setAttribute("loop", true);
this.audio.volume=1;
//Important part
var audioctx = new AudioContext();
var audioSrc = audioctx.createMediaElementSource(this.audio);
var analyser = audioctx.createAnalyser();
var gainNode = audioctx.createGain();
var fakeGainNode = audioctx.createGain();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant=0.5;
analyser.minDecibels=-100;
analyser.maxDecibels=0;
analyser.fftSize=2048;
//Connecting audioSrc to gainNode
audioSrc.connect(fakeGainNode);
audioSrc.connect(gainNode);
//Connecting gainNode to analyser
gainNode.connect(audioctx.destination);
//Connecting analyser to destination
//analyser.connect(gainNode);
//connect fake gain to analyser
fakeGainNode.connect(analyser);
gainNode.gain.value=0.3;
fakeGainNode.gain.value=0.05;
var size=analyser.frequencyBinCount;
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(size);
```

#### Changing source

```
this.next = function(){
    var next = ml.next();
    this.songName.innerHTML=next.name;
    this.changeSrc(next.url);
    if(playing)
        this.play();
}

this.prev = function(){
    var prev = ml.prev();
    this.songName.innerHTML=prev.name;
    this.changeSrc(prev.url);
    if(playing)
        this.play();
}

this.changeSrc = function(src){
    this.audio.src=src;
}
```

So the question is. Can I do anything to fix this on Firefox or is this just a bug and I should just stick to Chrome?

***Edit:*** I have put console logs throughout the functions that were problematic but all the logs come through and no errors are thrown

Comment: Please explain `does not work`. Also, can you provide SO Snippet to play with?

Comment: @Justinas I have explained what didn't work. And how should I provide a SO Snippet? Should I just use an `iframe`? Also the website doesn't really scale so wouldn't it be best to just follow the link?